# Application Insights not tracking SQL dependencies in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

For some reason Application Insights is not tracking SQL queries executed by my Azure Function. I have the following packages installed:

- Function `Version 3`
- Framework `netcoreapp3.1`

I can see calls to blob storage and HTTP calls but SQL is out the mix.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" Version="2.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
```

Host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
        "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
            "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
        },
        "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
        "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true
        }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

*EDIT*

Finally got this to work with `host.json` settings added but its not grouping the telemetry data. What I mean is, the SQL calls are being tracked seperately independent from the request. Usally you get a nice view and all dependencies are tracked as a group but this is no longer the case.

Comment: is it a simple sql query or EF used?

Comment: Using dapper to call into a sproc, no EF used here

Comment: any update for this item?

Answer (score 4):

Enabling application insights by click `Application insights` blade and turn the button to `enable` in azure function page,

[image]

then we can [got dependency for sql query by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies).

[image]

But if we wanna to see sql command in app insights when using function, we need to do further configuration, that is adding `"enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true` in host.json.

[image]

Here's my host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
          "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
        },
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And after changing the file, we can see text command in app insighs.

[image]